# angularjs - javascript - Convert object values from array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

I'm facing some problems with objects, json and etc in js. If some one can help me with something, it would be amazing! :)

I have an object, that I can't change, like this:

```
{
  "page": [
    "POST",
    "DELETE"
  ],
  "news": [
    "PUT"
  ]
}
```

I want to convert to be like this:

```
{
  "page": "POST, DELETE",
  "news": "PUT"
}
```

So I want the object values (arrays) to be string, I also tried toString(), String(), JSON.stringify, and other approaches from the internet, (maybe I had not done it right) but none worked for me, I'm kind of new on dealing with these type of data, so if some one can help me, TKS!! :D

### **EDIT:**

And in the case I got this structure:

```
{
  "page": {
    "POST": [
      "POST"
    ],
    "PUT": 122
  },
  "news": {
    "PUT": [
      "PUT"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I convert to be like:

```
{
  "page": "POST, PUT:122",
  "news": "PUT"
}
```

Comment: so loop over the object and use join

Comment: you've said *an object, that I can't change,* because the initial object should remain immutable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the initial object - it would be enough to use `Object.keys` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```js
var obj = {
  "page": [
    "POST",
    "DELETE"
  ],
  "news": [
    "PUT"
  ]
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
  obj[k] = obj[k].join(",");
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4));
```

**Additional solution** for another complex case:

```js
var obj = {
  "page": {
    "POST": [
      "POST"
    ],
    "PUT": 122
  },
  "news": {
    "PUT": [
      "PUT"
    ]
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
  var innerKeys = Object.keys(obj[k]), items = [];
  innerKeys.forEach(function(key) {
    items.push((Array.isArray(obj[k][key]))? key : key + ":" + obj[k][key]);
  });
  obj[k] = items.join(",");
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4));
```

Comment: Tks RomanPerekhrest, yours and @epascarello answers are the best ones. Actually, I can change the inicial structure at the save moment.

Comment: I made an edit @RomanPerekhrest, if u can help me with this second case it would be nice. Tks in advance! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @RomanPerekhrest, amazing implementation! I learned too much here. Tks

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, I'm studying here and i'm trying to do a reverse case on the complex one, trying to get the same structure back, with no success, if you can and if you have a time could help me? Thanks.

Comment: @LucasSantos, it's a good opportunity to create a new question with new problem description. After you created it, let me know

Comment: I made it @RomanPerekhrest, thank you, follow :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721814/angularjs-javascript-convert-object-values-from-string-to-array-structure

Answer (score 0):

With a assumption that your object will always have arrays as property values, you can do this using javascript like below

```
 var obj = {
     "page": [
         "POST",
         "DELETE"
     ],
     "news": [
         "PUT"
     ]
 };


 for (var o in obj) {
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
         obj[o] = obj[o].join(", ");
     }
 }

 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This works, but I think the Object.keys approach is better. Tks anyway @HectorBarbossa

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can add all values of an array up (concatenate them) to a string by using `var str = array.join(stringThatIsSupposedToBeInbetweenTheValues);`. So in your case that would be `array.join(', ');`. Note that this string is only put inbetween the single values, not around them (at the beginning or the end of the result). More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways to do it. Just need to loop over the object and set the array to a string.

```js
var obj = {
  "page": [
    "POST",
    "DELETE"
  ],
  "news": [
    "PUT"
  ]
};

Object.keys(obj).reduce( function (o, key) {  
    o[key] = o[key].join(", ");
    return o;
}, obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Probably would make sense to use forEach, but reduce works.

Comment: Tks epascarello, yours and @RomanPerekhrest answers are the best ones. I opt for the forEach approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this;

```js
var o = {
  "page": [
    "POST",
    "DELETE"
  ],
  "news": [
    "PUT"
  ]
},
    p = Object.keys(o).reduce((p,k) => (p[k] = o[k]+"",p),{});
console.log(p);
```

Comment: Thats looks great, but I got an error on Webstorm and JSHint testing this code. But looks just like @epascarello answer.

Comment: @LucasSantos That would probably be because you have ES6 disabled and that fat arrow function `(p,k) => (p[k] = o[k]+"",p),{})` doesn't work before ES6. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). To enable ES6 in WebStorm open Setting --> Lanuages & Frameworks --> JavaScript and choose ECMAScript 6 instead of 5.1

Comment: Nice @LBBO it's active now, I'm studying the ES6, got a book yesterday. :D